# Syntax of `-​- node`?

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the Ti*k*Z manual, I found the following command (simplified):

```
\draw (0,0) -- node {text} (0,1);
```

The effect of this is that a line is drawn from (0,0) to (0,1), and a text node is positioned halfway along the line:

[image]

I don't understand the syntax of this command:

According to the manual (14.2.1), the line-to path operation `--` takes a "coordinate or cycle" as an argument. But `node` is (among other things) a path operation in its own right (17.2.1), which would mean that here we have two path operations in a row without coordinates in between.

I guess `node` could also be seen as standing in for a coordinate, but only if one is given via `at`, which is not the case here. And anyway, in that case the line would only go to that specified coordinate.

Effectively `node` acts as a sort of option to `--`, but without the standard `[]` syntax.

Can someone shed light onto this?

Comment: While the default is the midpoint, one can also use things like [start] [end] [near start] etc., or more generally [pos=0.5].  If you place the node after the end point as in `(A) -- (B) node {text}` the default is [end], but you can still use the other options.

Comment: I found this useful `\draw (0,0) -- node[auto]{text} (0,1);` Try this with curves. For instance `\draw (0,0) to[bend left] node[auto] {text} (0,1);`

Answer (score 2):

Alright, found it. According to the manual section 17.9:

> The syntax of the line-to path operation is actually `-- [node<node specification>] <coordinate>`. (It is even possible to give multiple nodes in this way.) When the optional
> node is encountered, that is, when the `--` is directly followed by node, then the specification(s) are read and
> “stored away”. Then, after the `coordinate` has finally been reached, they are inserted again, but with the
> `pos` option set.

The "storing away" has limitations, therefore it might be better in general to use the syntax

```
\draw (0,0) -- (0,1) node[pos=0.5] {text};
```